# What sequence presets I must use with a GoPro and Adobe Premiere Pro CS 5.5?

Tags: premiere, action-cam, cs5

I use a GoPro which output is mp4 files.

I want to edit these movies into Adobe Premiere Pro CS 5.5. I'm a little lost about sequence presets to use.

I've got the choice between Digital SLR, AVCHD, XDCam, HDV... wow... I don't understand the differences between each other because when I use one or other, it seems to be the same. My gopro movie has a yellow bar at the top, saying that it needs rendering.

So, what's the difference with all of these formats and what's the best format to use with my GoPro ?

Answer (score 9):

In Premiere, a possible, easy approach would be importing your footage to the library before creating any sequence, then right click a clip and choose 'New Sequence from Clip'. Premiere will automatically adjust the settings according to the clip's properties.

This is also recommended by [Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/premiere/cs6/pdfs/adobe-premiere-cs6-quickstartguide-for-fcp-users.pdf) (3rd paragraph).

Answer (score 3):

A variation of this question has been answered on the Adobe Forums. Find it [here](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/668369).

> Sequence Preset
>
> Now that you have all your files converted, we need to pick the right
>   project sequence preset  for the resolution you are working on, all of
>   them based on AVCHD
>
> For R2 choose AVCHD 720p30
>
> For R3 use AVCHD 720p60
>
> For R4 you will need to create a custom profile, because there is no built-in profile for this resolution: Select AVCHD 1080p30 and then
>   go to the General tab. Change Editing Mode to Desktop, so  you will be
>   able to modify the resolution. Change the resolution to 1280 x 960 and
>   then press the Save Preset  button to save your newly created sequence
>   profile for GoPro R4
>
> For R5 use AVCHD 1080p30

Comment: thanks for that, but the provided thread explained how to use gopro movie on CS4. On CS4, you need to convert the video and use it in AVCHD. In CS5.5 you don't need to convert the video. Is it still AVCHD ?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed it was CS4. Was hoping it'd be the same. Give AVCHD a go and see if it works.

Comment: yes it works, like SLR or HDV. By the way, many format work but I don't know what's the differences between them and what's the best to choose ;)

Answer (score 2):

GoPro video files are basically the old Cineform Neoscene. GoPro bought them out. Cineform files have always worked in Premiere. I use them right in Premiere without any conversion. It is batter than the DSLR format. I convert all my Canon footage to the GoPro code before editing.

Just make your own preset and save it.